# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException caused by nested bean definition for Spring JPA

Tags: xml, spring, jpa

`Spring JPA 4.2.1`

Nested bean definition looks like below but gets
`NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`:

"No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined"

```
<bean id="tm" class="...JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory">
        <bean class="...LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource">
                <bean class="...BasicDataSource"
                    p:driverClassName="..." p:url="...">
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Only the flat definition works below, why?

```
<bean id="tm" class="...JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>
<bean id="emf" class="...LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
</bean>
<bean id="ds" class="...BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="..." p:url="...">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other bean also requires `EntityManagerFactory` (which one, I can't say - you didn't show the full stack trace). And [inner beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-inner-beans) are anonymous and they can't be retrieved using `BeanFactory.getBean()` or `@Autowired`, that's why you get this error in the first case.

> Inner beans are *always* anonymous and they are *always* created with the outer bean. It is *not* possible to inject inner beans into collaborating beans other than into the enclosing bean.

In the second case `EntityManagerFactoryBean` is not an inner bean and can be used by any other bean.